# What are the different virtual TTY numbers used for?

Tags: linux, tty

It seems by default (at least on Ubuntu, but I think I saw the same on other distros) there are virtual TTYs 1-6 for text login, 7 for GUI login, and 8 upwards are unused or at least non-interactive (here they show only a blinking cursor). *Is there a standard for which virtual TTYs should be used for what?*

Answer (score 3):

Up to whoever sets it up. Here on Fedora 18 (with `systemd`) `tty1` is graphical login, others are activated only if somebody tries to use them. What you describe is what the rough consensus was a year or two ago.

Comment: @l0b0, ctrl-alt-F2 gets me to the second tty, and `systemd` starts `getty` transparently when I do.