# What are TTYs >12 used for?

Tags: linux, tty

Related to [TTY numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71166/what-are-the-different-virtual-tty-numbers-used-for), it looks like there are 64 TTYs (`find /dev -name 'tty[0-9]*' | cut -c 9- | sort -n | tail -n 1` and [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt)). [tty0 is the current virtual console](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60649/3645), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> reports that it's connected to `tty1`, and `tty` in a GNOME terminal reports that it's connected to `/dev/pts/N`. Only TTYs 1 through 12 can be accessed using the well-known  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F*</kbd> keyboard shortcuts, so what are `/dev/ttyN` 13 through 64 used for?

Comment: May I ask why you ask about `12<N<64` instead of `7<N<64`? Are   7<N<13`  any different from `12<N<64`, or you already know what   7<N<13` are used for?

Comment: @Tim I've added a clarification.

Answer (score 8):

Again, as I answered to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71166/what-are-the-different-virtual-tty-numbers-used-for), it is entirely up to whoever sets the system up. Normally only a limited number of `getty`s are started, as people nowadays use X instead of a tty (or use `screen(1)`...), starting more than a handful is waste. If you want to start `getty`s on all 64, feel free.

The `pty` (and some other exotic starting letters) are pseudo `tty`s, faked by software to run e.g. `xterm`s and other `tty` users, in contrast to the "real" `tty`s (which aren't so real anymore...).

Answer (score 6):

Normally they are unused **.**
All `tty13`–`tty63`, when not specially activated, cost only 3 × 51 special files in `/dev/` (one `tty`, [one `vcs`, and one `vcsa`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72320/how-can-i-hook-on-to-one-terminals-output-from-another-terminal/72331) for each console), and 51 NULL pointers in the kernel memory. When a console is unused, kernel doesn’t allocate any data for it (besides aforementioned pointer in `vc_cons[]`).

Ask Linus Torvalds why he choose `#define MAX_NR_CONSOLES 63` (and not `31`, for example) in `tty.h`.

Answer (score 3):

Computers or other devices running Linux can have any number (including 0) of keyboards or input device of any shape and layout connected to them which can have any number of function keys.

The kernel in its default configuration allows up to 63 virtual consoles to be allocated and provides an API to map input events to switching consoles, and also to allocate/deallocate/switch console programmatically (see the `ioctl_console(2)` man page).

The `loadkeys` utility can be used to load that mapping, `dumpkeys` to dump it.

For instance, here with a typical British basic USB PC keyboard (with F1 .. F12 keys) connected to a PC running Ubuntu 18.04, `dumpkeys` indicates that consoles 1 to 12 can be switched to with Alt-F1 to Alt-F12, consoles 13 to 24 with AltGr-F1 to AltGr-F12, consoles 25 to 36 with Alt+Shift+F1 to Alt+Shift+F12, and I can use Alt+Left and Alt+Right to cycle through consoles (which allows me to access consoles above 36).

And I can allocate more consoles with `openvt` (though it's enough to *open* the tty device to allocate it) or switch between them with `chvt`.