# Take text "screenshot" of current terminal contents

Tags: shell, terminal, tty

I would like to, every 30 seconds or so, copy all text of a certain terminal or terminal emulator to a file, and display it in `conky`. I'm not talking about simple redirection (`command > file`), which doesn't work for ncurses programs or games such as NetHack.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: if it's a console terminal, you can get the contents from /dev/vcs*

Comment: That'll work! Is it possible to open more than the default 6 (or whatever your distro uses)?

Comment: You want text, so the accepted `screen` answer is indeed right. But for others who land here looking for a graphic screenshot of a Linux console running without X or any GUI, there is `fbgrab` as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/558588/8822

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no portable way to ask a terminal emulator to do screen dumps. You can work around this by running your application in GNU screen or tmux and using them to carry out the screen-dumps.

GNU screen can do this:

- [Can I take a text screenshot of a GNU Screen session?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/can-i-take-a-text-screenshot-of-a-gnu-screen-session-932703/)
- [Taking a screenshot of screen session over ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/557300/taking-a-screenshot-of-screen-session-over-ssh)

Likewise, there is a [plugin for tmux](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-logging) to do screen captures.

Answer (score 0):

capture the *visible* output of a process (text screenshot)

this will render special characters like carriage return (`\r`) and other [terminal control codes](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) as they would be visible to a human

for example, a live progress bar should produce

```
[================================>] 100%
```

and not

```
[==>                               ]  9%
[========>                         ] 28%
[==============>                   ] 47%
[=====================>            ] 65%
[===========================>      ] 84%
[================================>] 100%
```

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# text screenshot
# capture the visible output of a process
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697804/295986

captureCommand="$(cat <<'EOF'
  # example: progress bar
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/23630781/10440128
  for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
    sleep 0.1
    printf .
  done | pv -p -c -s 100 -w 40 > /dev/null
EOF
)"
# note: to stop the captureCommand after some time
# you can wrap it in `timeout -k 60 60`
# to stop after 60 seconds
# or use `for waiterStep in $(seq 0 60)`
# in the waiter loop

# create a new screen session. dont attach
screenName=$(mktemp -u screen-session-XXXXXXXX)
screen -S "$screenName" -d -m

# create lockfile
screenLock=$(mktemp /tmp/screen-lock-XXXXXXXX)
# remove lockfile after captureCommand
screenCommand="$captureCommand; rm $screenLock;"

echo "start captureCommand"
# send text to detached screen session
# ^M = enter
screen -S "$screenName" -X stuff "$screenCommand^M"
hardcopyFile=$(mktemp /tmp/hardcopy-XXXXXXXX)

enableWatcher=true
if $enableWatcher; then
  echo "start watcher"
  (
    # watcher: show live output while waiting
    while true
    #for watcherStep in $(seq 0 100) # debug
    do
      sleep 2
      # take screenshot. -h = include history
      screen -S "$screenName" -X hardcopy -h "$hardcopyFile"
      cat "$hardcopyFile"
    done
  ) &
  watcherPid=$!
fi

echo "wait for captureCommand ..."
while true
#for waiterStep in $(seq 0 60) # debug
do
  sleep 1
  [ -e "$screenLock" ] || break
done
echo "done captureCommand"

if $enableWatcher; then
  kill $watcherPid
fi

# take a last screenshot
screen -S "$screenName" -X hardcopy -h "$hardcopyFile"
echo "done hardcopy $hardcopyFile"

# kill the detached screen session
screen -S "$screenName" -X quit
```