# ttylog: no device is set

Tags: terminal, tty

I have two active ssh sessions:

```
~$ w
 22:51:42 up 17 days,  6:11,  3 users,  load average: 2,82, 2,38, 1,34
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user   pts/0    192.168.0.108    22:38   12:47   0.04s  0.04s -bash
user   pts/1    192.168.0.108    22:23    6.00s  0.19s  0.02s w
```

From tty0 I would like to see the output tty1. That is how I tried (as recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72334/40434)):

```
~$ ttylog pts/1
ttylog: no device is set. Use ttylog -h for more information.
```

Any ideas on how this command should be used to able to catch output of other terminals?

**Update:**

with `/dev/pts/1` getting the same error:

```
$ ttylog /dev/pts/1
ttylog: no device is set. Use ttylog -h for more information
```

**Update2:**

when using `-d` switch the source terminal is completely frozen.

```
ttylog -d /dev/pts/1
```

I have submitted a bug report about it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ttylog/+bug/1951725

Answer (score 0):

Use the full name of the device (the one you can `ls`):

```
ttylog /dev/pts/1
```

Your original command was looking for `pts/1` in the current directory, `$PWD`. It's not there.

Comment: thanks! but using /dev/pts/1 getting the same error - could you please try it in your env?

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: `crw--w---- 1 user tty 136, 1 nov   21 16:49 /dev/pts/1` that is the permissions